# Implementing ignoredProperties() on both a Object subclass and its own subclass

Tags: swift, realm

I'm new to Realm. I'm creating my models with a base class that inherits from Object, and custom subclasses of this base class. My model requires that the base class declares some properties as ignored by overriding the static `ignoredProperties()` method. When trying to override that method on some of the base class subclasses, I get a Swift compiler error stating that *Class method overrides a 'final' class method*. I don't have my base class implementation marked as `final`. I don't know if this is a current limitation with Realm but I can't seem to find any references to this issue.

My code looks like this:

```
class Base: Object {
    // properties declarations

    override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["someProperty"]
    }
}

class SomeModel: Base {
    // properties declarations

    // compiler error here
    override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
        var ignoredProperties = super.ignoredProperties()
        ignoredProperties.append("someOtherProperty")
        return ignoredProperties
    }
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions? I'm currently using the latest Realm from CocoaPods, on current Xcode (7.2.1) and latest Swift.

Comment: The documentation steers you away from model inheritance, and recommends object composition instead. What is the purpose of `Base`?

Comment: Hello @Michael, I am using `Base` mainly to define some common properties to all of my model classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've declared `ignoredProperties` as:

```
override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String]
```

It should be:

```
override class func ignoredProperties() -> [String]
```

`static` functions cannot be overridden by subclasses. `class` functions can.

Comment: This was precisely it. Thank you @bdash.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer didn't work for me, but what did was removing the override from the parent class and adding the fields you want to ignore from the parent class in the child's implementation of `ignoredProperties()`.