# realm ignoredProperties() show error

Tags: swift3, realm

I have applied both methods for ignoring `var photos = Array<RLMFile>()`but both methods show error in swift. I have write down errors with methods .

```
1.  public class func ignoredProperties() -> [AnyObject] {
        return ["photos" as AnyObject]
    }////this method give error :- method ignoredProperties() with objective-C selector 'ignoredProperties' conflicts with method 'ignoredProperties() from superclass
2.     override class func ignoredProperties() -> [AnyObject] {
        return ["photos" as AnyObject]
    }//this method give error :- Method does not override any method from its superclass
```

Comment: Try `public class func ignoredProperties() -> [StrIng]` instead.

Comment: `override class func ignoredProperties() -> [String]
    {
         return ["photos" as String]
    }`
`public  override class func ignoredProperties() -> [String]
    {
         return ["photos" as String]
    }`
I have done both but didn't work@HAS

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35619176/1489885) it should work, also my comment was wrong, I was on mobile and on the go, sorry! I meant `override class func ignoredProperties() -> [String]`. Have you tried `override class func ignoredProperties() -> [String] { return ["photos"] }`? This has to compile. What is the error?

Comment: `class Key : ModelWithPrimaryKey {
    var photos = Array<RLMFile>()
    //override class func ignoredProperties()
 //    public class func ignoredProperties() -> [AnyObject]?
//    {
//        return [ as AnyObject]
//    }
    override class func ignoredProperties() -> [String]
      {
        return ["photos"]
       }
    //    override  class func ignoredProperties() -> [String]? {
//        return ["photos" as String]
//    }
// }`
`class ModelWithPrimaryKey : RLMObject {
    }`

Comment: I have applied above way@HAS

Comment: I am implementing RLMObject so may be that not called

Comment: What is the error? Do you stell get a compilation error? You shouldn't, what else it not working?

Comment: I didn't get any error because it's not working